Insert Rows To New Worksheet Without Named Range
Is there any way of amending the below code to insert the rows onto the new worksheet but not copying the named range? When copying to the sheet named CSV, after entering the destination row I get a message box with the message shown here - 
Sub CopyToNewSheet()

Dim Last_Row As Long
Last_Row = Sheets("CSV").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

Dim c As Range, d, a As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set c = Application.InputBox("Select the row(s) to be copied.", Type:=8)
d = Application.InputBox("Enter the row number where to insert." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The next free row is " & Last_Row + 1 & ".", Type:=1)
On Error GoTo 0
If c Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The source rows were not selected"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf TypeName(d) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "The destination row was not entered"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each a In c.Areas
    a.EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets("CSV").Rows(Val(d)).EntireRow.Insert
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.GoTo Sheets("CSV").Range("A1"), True
Rows("5:100").RowHeight = 15
End Sub

I have no idea where to even begin with leaving out the named range as I don't want those on the CSV sheet!
Or is there even a way to edit the code so that it just selects yes on that message box without me having to each time?

What does the message say? That link is banned in my office

"The name xxx already exists. Click Yes to use that version of the name, or click No to rename the version  you're moving of copying"

Also to add, I did try .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues instead of EntireRow.Insert but this wouldn't allow me to copy rows that had gaps between eg rows 5,10,27 - it would only copy one.
